# Automatically freezing objects after initialization

Tags: ruby, oop, immutability, freeze

I'm tired of adding `freeze` at the end of method `initialize` of my classes all the time like this:

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    # some stuff
    freeze
  end
end
```

I would like to do this by default for any object. I thought of overriding `BasicObject#initialize` inside `Object` class, which provides method `freeze`, but I don't see how.

Comment: I have to ask: why do you want to do this? It will make all objects unmutable.

Comment: Why would you need to freeze objects ? you can manage what attributes can be changed using `attr_reader` and `attr_writer` as well as `private` and `protected` keywords to signal what your interface allows

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to freeze objects. I've never needed to do so in an initializer, so the request is for either a very esoteric, corner case, or, due to a misunderstanding of how to write in Ruby. As is, this seems like an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and you haven't explained *WHY* you need to do this, only that you want to, and if you said why we'd help you understand better why it's not needed.

Comment: The reason is I like to kill mutants :) By this way, I'll be sure that everything is immutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you asked the question...

You could do this via monkey patching and `alias_method` chaining

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> class Object
irb(main):002:1>   alias_method :old_init, :initialize
irb(main):003:1>
irb(main):004:1*   def initialize
irb(main):005:2>     old_init
irb(main):006:2>     self.freeze
irb(main):007:2>   end
irb(main):008:1> end
(irb):4: warning: redefining Object#initialize may cause infinite loop
```

That said; this is absolutely a terrible idea and I suspect it will break some core Ruby functionality. Notice even irb is saying, "Whoa! Don't do this" => `warning: redefining Object#initialize may cause infinite loop`

It would be a much better idea to define your own class that extends from Object; define a new version of initialize there that calls up to Object's initialize and then calls freeze.  From there you can have your classes inherit from this subclass.

Comment: +1 "this is absolutely a terrible idea and I suspect it will break some core Ruby functionality". It is a terrible idea, and smells of a misunderstanding of how to code in Ruby, and objects in general.

Comment: If it is the same as manually freeze each instance, it will not break anything. Imperative programming's side effects are terrible.

Comment: The old adage "When in Rome, do as the Romans do." is good advice. In most real world applications you will be relying on outside gems, and a certain level of trust must be taken to get work accomplished. At some point this change is going to cause things to break, because at it's core Ruby is an imperative language. When I'm using Erlang I do things the Erlang way; there immutability just happens, because that is part of the beliefs of the language. Ruby is the antithesis of immutability. Open classes are proof of this. And when someone monkey patches your monkey patch.. oh boy...

Comment: I agree. I'm using this _protection_ from test environment, only. Just to be sure that my objects are unmuted.